# Foundation: How to responsively switch between Basic Menu and Dropdown Menu?

Tags: javascript, menu, zurb-foundation, responsive

Using Foundation, I'm trying to make a responsive menu that switches from basic view to dropdown view, and vice versa, depending on media size (mobile or desktop). Is it supported in Foundation or should I implement it by myself?

Mobile view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9eLw.jpg

Desktop view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjiIa.jpg

I have written a Jquery code that moves the menu content from one place to another, depending on media size.

HTML code:

```
<ul class="dropdown menu" id="desktop-place" data-dropdown-menu>
    <li class="show-for-small-only">
        <a>Drop</a>
        <ul class="menu" id="mobile-place">
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="content"><a>One</a></li>
    <li class="content"><a>Two</a></li>
    <li class="content"><a>Three</a></li>
    <li class="content"><a>Four</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS code:

```
$(document).foundation();

function moveFromBasicToDropdown() {
    $('#mobile-place').append($('.content'));
}
function moveFromDropdownToBasic() {
    $('#desktop-place').append($('.content'));
}

$(window).on('changed.zf.mediaquery', function(event, newSize, oldSize) {
    if (newSize === 'small') {
        moveFromBasicToDropdown();
    }
    else {
        moveFromDropdownToBasic();
    }
});

if (Foundation.MediaQuery.is('small only')) {
    moveFromBasicToDropdown();
}
else {
    moveFromDropdownToBasic();
}
```

The code works as expected. However, I am not sure if this feature is already supported in Foundation; if not, then I'm wondering if this is the right way to implement it?